# Make a java timeout the easiest way

Tags: java

I want to make timeout in java, but in the easiest way.
I tried lots of these codes, but they didn't seem to work.
I need something like a pause for 10 seconds for example.

Something like:

```
    System.out.println("start");
[wait 10 seconds]
    System.out.println("end");
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Did that include `Thread.sleep(10*1000)`? Why did that not work?

Comment: The question is, do you want to do anything while the "time out" is running?

Comment: The title say "timeout".  Timeout from doing what?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, using [`Thread.sleep()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-):

```
System.out.println("start");
Thread.sleep(10000);
System.out.println("end");
```

Comment: @TomLenc Do you have multiple threads running? If not, the above snippet pauses execution for your single running thread, and has been known to work since 1995.

Comment: @TomLenc You're going to have to provide more context. With the information you've provided (virtually none), this is the best I can come up with.

Comment: @TomLenc "Doesn't work for me" is not a problem description. You need to try harder.

Answer (score 1):

The `Thread` class's `sleep()` method can serve this purpose.  It take the number of milliseconds to sleep as an argument, and will stop execution of the invoking thread for at least that amount of time:

```
System.out.println("start");
Thread.sleep(10000) // 10 seconds or 10,000 mili seconds
System.out.println("end");
```